# How to make the install target dependend on generated (protobuf) files

Tags: cmake, dependencies

We have a project, where we have different applications, which come with protobuf definitions, for which we provide python bindings as a side effect. We ran into the problem, that when we want to install them along with the rest of the software, cmake complains that the binding to be created does not exist.

This is a minimal sample which behaves wrong:

```
// foo.proto
message Foo {
    uint32 foo = 1;
}

# CMakeLists.txt
project(foobar)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

protobuf_generate_cpp(FOO_SRC FOO_HDR foo.proto)
protobuf_generate_python(FOO_PY foo.proto)

install(FILES ${FOO_PY} DESTINATION "share/proto/")

$ make install
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/foobar
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/tmp/foobar/foo_pb2.py": No such file or
  directory.
```

How can I convince CMake to build the bindings when I run `make install`?

Answer (score 2):

Functions `protobuf_generate_cpp` and `protobuf_generate_python` are actually create **custom commands** ([add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html)). This is noted in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html#command:protobuf_generate_python) for these functions.

For make a custom command to work, it should be some **target** which **consumes** (or **depends** on) the files created by the custom command.

In case of `protobuf_generate_cpp`, consumption is usually performed with `add_library`/`add_executable` commands.

But it is possible to create a custom target which depends on given files:

```cmake
protobuf_generate_cpp(FOO_SRC FOO_HDR foo.proto)
protobuf_generate_python(FOO_PY foo.proto)

add_custom_target(proto_target ALL DEPENDS ${FOO_SRC} ${FOO_HDR} ${FOO_PY})
```

Comment: Is it possible to split the `add_custom_target` declaration and the dependencies? I tried to do a `add_custom_target(proto_target ALL)` followed by `add_target_dependencies(proto_target ${FOO_PY})`, but this does not work, while `add_custom_target(proto_target ALL DEPENDS ${FOO_PY}))` does. This is part of a larger system, where it would be convenient for me if I only had to introduce one target, and add dependencies later (this is part of some internal functions which I don't want to create lots of targets). Also I have no clue where to search in the doc for this behavior.

Comment: Dependency from **files** can only be specified with `DEPENDS` clause when create the custom target. Moreover, if a file is generated by `add_custom_command`, then it could be added only to the target in the **same directory**: This is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). But at any time you could "attach" to the target other **targets** using [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) command.